# ASP.Net with nginx/Lighttpd/mono/fastcgi on Windows

Tags: windows, nginx, mono, fastcgi, lighttpd

I need to run a web server (nginx or lighttpd) on Windows in order to serve the basics requirements for an ASP.Net application. I'm trying to use the fastcgi-mono-server4 from mono 2.10 for windows without any luck.
My ASP.Net application is just an httpmodule with a minimal global.asax to initialize, and I use my own mvc framework so I need really too little from asp.
I don't serve any specific file extension, and all the requests must be sent to the module handler. I'm trying to configure both servers with all the settings found on the web and fastcgi-mono-server4 with all possible commands lines, and the fastcgi-mono-server4 seems to work and both web servers too but in the best scenario I just got a "No Application defined for..." page or a 500 server error, and the fastcgi sometimes shows a "No application defined for index.html" or just debug info or nothing at all (in different configurations).
I just need the correct configuration for nginx/lighttpd and the correct command line for the fastcgi.
The app could run on mono or .net framework (it's running on apache/mono without problems) and I don't want to use IIS on windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your nginx config file?

Comment: This is the [nginx.conf](http://pastebin.com/cRzeNpEH)

And this is the bat (running in the application directory)
 e:\Prog\Mono210\lib\mono\4.0\fastcgi-mono-server4.exe /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000  /applications=/:/.

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

It has been quite a while since I've used nginx to host my ASP.NET application, but looking back at my nginx.conf there are a couple differences. First, I used to redirect every request, no matter the extension, to the fastcgi socket. Also, I had a `root` directive to the root of my Web Application. This is the `location` part of my nginx.conf:

```
    location / {
        root /home/whatever/Website/;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

I really have no idea about what is sent to the fastcgi socket, but you could give the `root` directive a try, as well as redirecting everything to it (kind of like the integrated pipeline model).
Also, my first two lines of my fastcgi_params in case it helps:

```
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO      "";
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

I used this with Mono 2.10.8 and my ASP.NET MVC 3 website worked perfectly. Try it out and talk back to me.

Comment: I'm still getting many kind of errors.
If my app is in e:\work\website\ (the bin, global asax, etc) how the "root" parameter must be? I try with e:\\work.., /work/ and others but not sure how it must be in windows (not linux).

Comment: Thank you Zabani. Finally "works" (in fact it doesn't, but due to mono limitations on vb.net I get a VBNC_CRASH.
The root seems not to be necessary, at least in my case when I don't need to server others sites.
The problem was in the fasctcgi bat which start the fastcgi-mono-server4, where the parameter starting with E: casuses the problem.
I changed to /applications=/:/..\work\website\ and works.
I trying to run the fastcgi-mono-server4 in .net (without mono) and works but report an error about a missing assembly fastcgi-mono-server4 (!), and running via mono works but not vb.net

Comment: Good to know about this stuff. Hope you find some way to get things working!